# Is the closure of a set $A$ in the Zariski topology $V(A)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a commutative unitary ring and $A\subseteq \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ a subset. If $A=\{p\}$, then the closure $\bar A$ of $A$ equals $V(p)=\{x\in \operatorname{Spec}(R) \mid p\subseteq x\}$. Is this true for an arbitrary subset $A$ as well, i.e. is $\bar A=V(A)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we have $\overline{A} = V(\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p} \in A} \mathfrak{p})$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is an argument for your equality? I see that for an ideal $I$, one has $V(I)=V(rad(I))=V(\cap_{I\subseteq \mathfrak{p}}\mathfrak{p})$ and perhaps this relates when $I$ is the ideal generated by $A$? Is there also a description for $V(A)$ or is this an uninteresting closed set?

Comment: Since $\overline{A}=V(I(A))$, you can use your formula to get the result.

Comment: With $I(A)$ you mean $I(A)=\{f\in R\mid f(x)=0 \forall x\in A\}$? Is then $\bar A=V(I(A))$ true in the general situation without $R$ being a finitely generated $K$-algebra and $K$ algebraically closed? (Also $V(A)$ has no nice description, has it?) Thank you.

Comment: $\overline{A}=V(I(A))$ holds by abstract nonsense, since the right hand is clearly the smallest closed subset containing $A$, by the general properties of $V(-)$ and $I(-)$. Nothing deep here. And of course this works for every commutative ring.

Comment: $V(A)$ should be seen as $V(\sum_{\mathfrak{p} \in A} \mathfrak{p})$. Sums of prime ideals can be arbitrary complicated, I guess.